# PHP Notice: Undefined offset array file can't upload

Tags: php, arrays, csv, import

I already open all question which related my post, but I'm still confuse. I try to import my csv file using php.

I try this [tutorial](http://www.johnboy.com/scripts/import-csv-file-with-php-mysql/import.phps). But I got this error :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: csv
```

I've modify to my database:

```
if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0) { 
    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database

//    do { 
        while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")){
        print_r($data);
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO prod_schedule (RecNo,      Model_Name,     Lot_Number,     Start_Serial,
                                Qty,    Lot_Qty, Line,   Line_Name,      Start_Date,     End_Date,       Due_Date
                        ) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } 
//      while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    // 
    //redirect 
    header('Location: upload.php?success=1'); die; 

}
```

---

print_r($data) result is:

```
Array ( [0] => RecNo Model_Name Lot_Number Start_Serial Qty Lot_Qty Line Line_Name Start_Date End_Date Due_Date ) Array ( [0] => 1 KD-R746BTU9D 011A 421 30 80 N0001 MA 01 3/3/2014 3/3/2014 12/31/2999 ) Array ( [0] => 2 KW-XG56T2UD 057A 25081 79 440 N0001 MA 01 3/3/2014 3/3/2014 12/31/2999 ) Array ( [0] => 3 KD-R646U9D 012B 561 1 60 N0001 MA 01 3/3/2014 3/3/2014 12/31/2999 )
```

---

EDIT

change `while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")){` become `while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"\t","'")){`.Then print_r($data) :

```
array(1) { ["csv"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "prod_schedule.csv" ["type"]=> string(8) "text/csv" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpb1ji8u" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(1943264) } }

Array ( [0] => RecNo [1] => Model_Name [2] => Lot_Number [3] => Start_Serial [4] => Qty [5] => Lot_Qty [6] => Line [7] => Line_Name [8] => Start_Date [9] => End_Date [10] => Due_Date ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => KD-R746BTU9D [2] => 011A [3] => 421 [4] => 30 [5] => 80 [6] => N0001 [7] => MA 01 [8] => 3/3/2014 [9] => 3/3/2014 [10] => 12/31/2999 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => KW-XG56T2UD [2] => 057A [3] => 25081 [4] => 79 [5] => 440 [6] => N0001 [7] => MA 01 [8] => 3/3/2014 [9] => 3/3/2014 [10] => 12/31/2999 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => KD-R646U9D [2] => 012B [3] => 561 [4] => 1 [5] => 60 [6] => N0001 [7] => MA 01 [8] => 3/3/2014 [9] => 3/3/2014 [10] => 12/31/2999 )
```

file still not uploaded, show :`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: csv`. Then put `var_dump` like :

```
var_dump($_FILES);
if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0) {
```

I got `array(0) { }`.

Comment: *"I try this tutorial. But I got this error"* --- That's not a tutorial, it's code.

Comment: Is there a blank line in your csv?  Have you tried a print_r($data); to see what it contains so you can troubleshoot the code? I'm guessing it's from an old tutorial too, as you really shouldn't use mysql_* functions which are obsolete in newer PHP versions, read up on using mysqli_* functions instead. There is also no escaping or sanatising of data which leaves this script wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Even if it were a tutorial, it uses the deprecated ext/mysql API. You should look for something better than that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: that's a link file from some sites.

Comment: See this Q&A on SO => http://stackoverflow.com/q/21332380/ it might help. @nunu

Comment: @flauntster: see the result of `print_r($data)` at my updated post.

Comment: You need to provide a sample CSV of your data @nunu

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing through, I think

```
 if (!empty($_GET[success]))
```

should be

```
 if (!empty($_GET['success']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem i think is how you placed your do while. when using a do while statement, it will first run the code inside the do, then checks the while statement.

What you should do, instead of

```
 do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."'
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

USE

```
 while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")){
      if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."'
            )
        ");
    }



 }
```

Its basically the same, it just execute the code in `while()` first before doing any of the code inside.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the output of print_r($data) that you provided, I can see that the fields look to be tab separated.

Your code here:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")){
```

is looking for the standard comma delimiter between fields using the [fgetcsv][1] function - which is common practise, as CSV stands for Comma Separated Values.

To get your script to read the values in using tabs as delimiters, try adjusting the above line to:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"\t","'")){
```

Hope this helps :)
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: show `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: csv` at line 1 of my php script.

Comment: line 1 = if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0) { .. which tells me it's not receiving the file upload from the form.

Comment: if not receiving any file, why after print_r($data) I got the result ?

Comment: try putting a var_dump($_FILES) at the top of your code, to see what $_FILES contains